# For … Next with If generates Compile Error Next Without For

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to update an Excel sheet to send reminders. This Excel sheet has a list of people and when they were certified to use certain equipment.

The sheet calculates how many days it has been since they received certification, as well as how many days before they have to recertify.

I am trying to make a script that reads the column with how many days the person has before recertification, and if it is less than, say 30 days, automatically sends an email.

I followed a tutorial, but it sends to all that are listed. I tried to modify it to check the "F" column, "days since certification," to send to those that are less than or equal to 30.

When I try to run this, it says

> Compile Error Next Without For.

```vb
Sub CreateCourseCertificates()
    Dim EApp As Object
    Set EApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim EItem As Object
    Dim RList As Range
    Set RList = Range("A2", Range("a2").End(xlDown))
    Dim R As Range
    Dim daysSinceCert As Range
    Set daysSinceCert = Range("F2", Range("f2").End(xlDown))
    For Each R In RList
        If daysSinceCert <= 30 Then
            Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
            With EItem
                .To = R.Offset(0, 2)
                .Subject = "Test"
                .Body = "Test"
                .Display
            End With
    Next R
    Set EApp = Nothing
    Set EItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You need an `End If` to match up with `If daysSinceCert <= 30 Then`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/ifthenelse-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
Dim daysSinceCert As Range
Set daysSinceCert = Range("F2", Range("f2").End(xlDown))
```

and instead use `Offset` to refer to the corresponding cell in column F as you loop:

```
For Each R In RList
    If R.Offset(,5).Value <= 30 Then
        Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
        With EItem
            .To = R.Offset(,2).Value
            .Subject = "Test"
            .Body = "Test"
            .Display
        End With
    End If
Next
```